# Angularjs ngtagInput library load more data on scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, ng-tags-input

I have a text field, which auto suggest the list fetched from API, now I want to load more data when the scroller reaches end eg:

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos
Please go to last column, second option "Tags input and autocomplete with custom templates", you can see a scroller in this example, now when the user scroll to the end of the list, make an API call to fetch more data.

Tried adding `lrinfiniteScroll library` to the div(just above the `<tag-input>` as well to the `<tag-input>` and even to `<auto-complete>` but nothing worked as the inner div's are dynamically generated by the library.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
<div>
   <tags-input data-ng-model=“tags” display-property=“name" lr-infinite-scroll="dimensionAutoFilter.loadMoreData">
        <auto-complete source=“loadTags($query)” ></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>

</div>
```

Thanks